# Command pabot not found in docker version of Robotframework browser

Tags: robotframework, playwright

I'm trying to run Pabot / robot framework-browser script in Docker.

I have tryed to use command:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/test" --ipc=host --user pwuser --security-opt seccomp=Docker/seccomp_profile.json -e "enviroment=***" -e "ROBOT_THREADS=10" -e PABOT_OPTIONS="--testlevelsplit" marketsquare/robotframework-browser:latest bash -c "pabot . -i smoke --outputdir /test/output /test"
```

Result:  bash: pabot: command not found

Whats wrong in that syntax??
If i use "robot -i Smoke --outputdir /test/output /test"" then execution works ok (no errors).

Comment: Debug the container by starting it and ssh into it then run `pabot --version` . Probably is not in the PATH.

Comment: PS **:\***\****> pabot --version
A parallel executor for Robot Framework test cases.
Version 2.1.0                                                                                                                                                                  Robot Framework 4.1.2 (Python 3.10.0 on win32)
Total testing: 0.0 seconds
Elapsed time:  0.2 seconds

Comment: I mean inside the container, you show Windows: Python 3.10.0 on win32
Try `docker run (...) bash` then `docker exec -ti container_id /bin/bash`.

Comment: hmm, that docker command created image only (sorry i'm new in docker world). could that be the reason

Answer (score 0):

I checked and confirmed that the image does not have `pabot` installed. You can build an image locally with `docker build -f Dockerfile .`.

Here is an example of the execution with that image, but installing missing dependencies:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/atest:/atest -v /tmp:/tmp -e "ROBOT_THREADS=10" -e PABOT_OPTIONS="--testlevelsplit" --ipc=host --user pwuser --security-opt seccomp=seccomp_profile.json marketsquare/robotframework-browser:latest bash -c "pip install robotframework-pabot psutil && pabot --outputdir /tmp/test/output atest/test"
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. Managed to continue. to next error message
Storing .pabotsuitenames file
[ WARNING ]: storing .pabotsuitenames failed
[ERROR] EXCEPTION RAISED DURING PABOT EXECUTION
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/issues/449